# How to install cvxopt without downgrading mkl and python

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, cvxopt

**Environment**:
OS = Windows 10, Python ver = 3.7.0, mkl ver = 2019.0-118, conda ver = 4.5.12. All up to date as of now (2019/1/13).

**Issue**:
When attempting `conda install cvxopt`, it prompts at the end:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    mkl:                                2019.0-118              --> 2018.0.3-1
    python:                             3.7.0-hea74fb7_0        --> 3.6.8-h9f7ef89_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

I don't want to downgrade either. Actually, when I visit the cvxopt's [installation page](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html) it states clearly that

> Wheels for Windows:
>
> - are available for Python 27, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, and 3.7 (64 bit only)

The suggested [installation procedure](http://cvxopt.org/install/index.html#windows) is a bit complicated, though.

I'm just wondering if there's a simple way (that is, for dummies) such as a one-line command that can install cvxopt without compromising python or mkl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best not to mix `conda` and `pip` packages. It looks like `conda-forge` has the latest version of `cvxopt`, so simply do:

```
conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just try `pip3 install cvxopt`

I've just tried it and it works on my Windows machine

Comment: Thanks. Are you also using 3.7?

Comment: Nope, I'm using 3.6.5, but it shouldn't make a difference because I see the 3.7 .whl file available on pypi here: https://pypi.org/project/cvxopt/#files

Comment: It seems that I don't have `pip3` via conda channels. Also when I try `pip install pip3` it reports `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip3 (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pip3`. So may I ask where it's convenient to obtain `pip3`? (Using conda it tells me my pip is up to date.)

Comment: Could you open up your cmd.exe in your Start Menu, run it with admin privileges and try `pip3 install cvxopt`? If that doesn't work, try `pip -V`. Let me know the result so I can further help you.

Comment: Thanks. `pip3` not found, and `pip` version is 18.1

Comment: If `pip3` is not found, could you run in `python -V` to see the current python version in that same cmd.exe? It seems weird to me that you mention you have python 3.7 and pip but do not have pip3.

Comment: it returns 3.7.0. In fact I installed Anaconda directly, not the official release. Is there anyway to get pip3 manually then?

Comment: You could try `pip install cvxopt` to see if it works in cmd, otherwise, you could do it in your conda env and run `pip install cvxopt` to try too. If that still doesn't work, then the issue is with Anaconda not having the most updated packages in its managed env. The last resort is actually to forsake Anaconda if you really must have the latest cvxopt and simply do a fresh Python installation with the packages that you directly want. Functionally, there is no difference, you just lose the Anaconda env and packaging. Should you choose the last option, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help! Sorry I'm going to sleep now, is it okay if I try your suggestions tomorrow morning? I'll update you about the results.

Comment: Sure no prob, do let me know

Comment: Alrite. I tried the other answers suggestion and successfully installed cvxopt without downgrading python or mkl.

Comment: @Vim No problem, remember to mark his answer as the correct one. In the long term though, I do suggest you switch directly to using Python download instead of Anaconda because it is easier to maintain